# Upload images via CSV data onto server

Tags: php, excel, file-upload, csv, upload

We have a site where users can add listings and they can optionally add images to these listings. Now we are working on a `Excel` bulk lister which spits out a formatted `CSV` file. However we're wondering how we can go about doing the image upload part as obviously it's not going to work if the user just enters the location of the image on their hard drive.

Is there any other method we can do what we are wanting to achieve? ...or will we need to think outside the box here?

Comment: This question is maybe a bit too broad for this forum, but one appraoch would be to have users also upload a zip file containing all their images, with image name being a column in the CSV.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah, that's similar to what I was thinking. Users could upload a file into a "gallery" and then input the image name(s) into the image field. Might have to go with that idea, just thought I'd ask here as I'm sure this has come up before.

Comment: Nobody came up with an answer yet? Been trying to achieve this as well but can't figure out where to start... Definitely don't want users to have to zip and upload images before putting it in the csv :(

Comment: @BillWhickomb I believe we just had users enter in existing image locations; not sure there is an easy way around that unfortunately.